# Appengine Key serializes transient appIdNamespace

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I am creating a `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key` in namespace `A` and adding it as a field to `DeferredTask` to run in different namespace `B`. That task is then sent to a Queue and is being executed on a different box.

Because, it is created in namespace A that key has `A` as its original namespace value (in its `appIdNamespace` field).

But as the key's `appIdNamespace` field is transient and `DeferredTask` uses serialization I expect the `appIdNamespace` field to be null on deserialization (and thus to get initialised to have namespace value of `B`) when being run from namespace `B`.

But instead key still has `A` as a value for namespace in its `appIdNamespace` field after deserialization, when task runs in namespace `B`.

I am sure I am missing something here, but can't explain. What am I missing here?

Comment: Serialization process might be overridden for the `Key` which serializes the `appIdNamespace` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I just checked. Serialization process *is* overridden for `Key` which serializes the `appIdNamespace` if it's not `null` via the `appId` field which is not `transient`:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    if (appIdNamespace != null) {
      appId = appIdNamespace.toEncodedString();
    }
    out.defaultWriteObject();
}
```

And `readObject()` properly decodes the `appIdNamespace` from the deserialized `appId` field:

```
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    in.defaultReadObject();
    if (appId != null) {
        appIdNamespace = AppIdNamespace.parseEncodedAppIdNamespace(appId);
        appId = null;
    } else {
        appIdNamespace = new AppIdNamespace(DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppId(), "");
    }
    validateAppIdNamespace(parentKey, appIdNamespace);
}
```

Source: [Key.java](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key.java)

Comment: Thanks, this explains the mystery. Now makes sense. Although comment would be useful in documentation, to warn about that.